# Is there a $p$-adic version of the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Is there a $p$-adic version of the Riemann hypothesis or this does not make any sense?

Comment: Like [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2003.08.008)?

Comment: Yes. Can we hope for a motivic analogue too? By the way I can't buy the article, I don't know if you have a copy.

Comment: What, a copy like [this](http://www.math.uci.edu/~dwan/doug.pdf)?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: @J.M. perhaps combine your comments into an answer?

Comment: @lhf: Not having $p$-adic expertise, I think I'll let somebody else write a meatier answer. All I did was throw a few terms into Google Scholar...

Comment: @J.M., evidently that's more than OP did, so go for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(due to insistent public demand)

> Is there a $p$-adic version of the Riemann hypothesis?

– [Certainly!](http://www.math.uci.edu/~dwan/doug.pdf)